# MYSQL - Timeclock Count Hours In/Out for each day of current week

Tags: mysql, php

Below is my table for my database `timeclock` that records each record of an employee clocking in/out. I am wanting to create a function that returns hours for each day Monday-Sunday of current week.

```
id  user    timeinout           type    function    
1   1   2015-08-05 20:20:32     in         1
2   1   2015-08-05 20:20:56     out        1
3   1   2015-08-05 20:29:25     in         1
4   1   2015-08-05 20:32:04     out        2
5   1   2015-08-05 20:36:28     in         1
6   1   2015-08-05 20:40:00     out        1
7   1   2015-08-06 09:05:39     in         1
```

I know this function is way wrong, but here is where I am. I have never done this before so I am at a real loss and all examples I have tried have failed.

```
function gettimeclockHours($user) {
  include $_SESSION['db'];
  try {
      $sql = "SELECT HOUR(timeinout) as hour, COUNT(*) as num_rows FROM timeclock WHERE user = :user GROUP BY HOUR(timeinout)";
      $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $s->bindValue(':user', $user);
      $s->execute();
  }
  catch (PDOException $e)
  {
      $error = 'Error.' . $e->getMessage();
      moduleError($error);
      exit();
  }
  $result = $s->fetch();
  return $result;
}
```

The Output example I am looking for is below.

```
Day of Week                  Total Time
Monday                       1.2 Hours
Tuesday     
Wednesday                    3.0 Hours
Thursday    
Friday  
Saturday    
Sunday  
Total for current results    4.2 Hours
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Do you want to know how much time each user has between each `in` and `out` from each day?

Comment: What I am wanting is the total amount of time the user has for the whole day that they are clocked in.

Comment: So, you want the time between `2015-08-05 20:20:32` AND `2015-08-05 20:40:00`? Or every time spend between `2015-08-05 20:20:32` as `in` and `2015-08-05 20:20:56` as `out`?

Comment: ideally for each day I would like to calculate time between 2015-08-05 00:00:00 and 2015-08-06 00:00:00 or whatever day is input.

Comment: Do in's sometimes occur on day before the next out?

Comment: basically this is a clock in/out system for are hourly employees. The user could clock in/out as many times in a day as they need to. Each Monday we are going to run a report for user and shows time they put in each day from the previous Monday to Sunday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get it using [`MIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min),[`MAX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) and [`WEEKDAY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) with your actual design:

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`timeclock` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` INT NULL,
  `timeinout` DATETIME NULL,
  `type` ENUM('in', 'out') NULL,
  `function` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );
```

**Data:**

```
insert into timeclock(id,user,timeinout,type,function)VALUES
('1','1','2015-07-27 20:20:32','in','1'),
('2','1','2015-07-27 20:20:56','out','1'),
('3','1','2015-07-27 20:29:25','in','1'),
('4','1','2015-07-28 20:32:04','out','2'),
('5','1','2015-07-28 20:36:28','in','1'),
('6','1','2015-07-29 20:40:00','out','1'),
('7','1','2015-07-29 20:45:39','in','1'),
('8','1','2015-07-30 20:20:32','in','1'),
('9','1','2015-07-30 20:20:56','out','1'),
('10','1','2015-07-31 20:29:25','in','1'),
('11','1','2015-07-31 20:32:04','out','2'),
('12','1','2015-08-01 20:36:28','in','1'),
('13','1','2015-08-01 20:40:00','out','1'),
('14','1','2015-08-02 20:20:32','in','1'),
('15','1','2015-08-02 20:20:56','out','1'),
('16','1','2015-08-02 20:29:25','in','1'),
('17','1','2015-08-02 20:32:04','out','2'),
('18','1','2015-08-02 20:36:28','in','1'),
('19','1','2015-08-02 20:40:00','out','1');
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
    tc.user,
    tcmin.min,
    tcmax.max,
    CASE 
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=0 THEN 'Monday' 
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=1 THEN 'Tuesday'
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=2 THEN 'Wednesday'
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=3 THEN 'Thursday'
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=4 THEN 'Friday'
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=5 THEN 'Saturday'
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=6 THEN 'Sunday' END AS WeekDay,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,tcmin.min,tcmax.max) AS Minutes
FROM test.timeclock AS tc
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
            user,
            MIN(timeinout) as min
          FROM test.timeclock
          GROUP BY user,DATE(timeinout)) as tcmin
    ON (tcmin.user=tc.user AND DATE(tcmin.min)=DATE(tc.timeinout))
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
            user,
            MAX(timeinout) as max
          FROM test.timeclock
          GROUP BY user,DATE(timeinout)) as tcmax
    ON (tcmax.user=tc.user AND DATE(tcmax.max)=DATE(tc.timeinout))
WHERE 
    tc.timeinout>='2015-07-27'
    AND tc.timeinout<'2015-08-03'
    AND tc.user=1
GROUP BY tc.user,DATE(tc.timeinout)
ORDER BY tc.timeinout ASC;
```

**Test:**

```
mysql> SELECT 
    -> tc.user,
    -> tcmin.min,
    -> tcmax.max,
    -> CASE 
    -> WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=0 THEN 'Monday' 
    -> WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=1 THEN 'Tuesday'
    -> WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=2 THEN 'Wednesday'
    -> WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=3 THEN 'Thursday'
    -> WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=4 THEN 'Friday'
    -> WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=5 THEN 'Saturday'
    -> WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=6 THEN 'Sunday' END AS WeekDay,
    -> TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,tcmin.min,tcmax.max) AS Minutes
    -> FROM test.timeclock AS tc
    -> LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
    -> user,
    -> MIN(timeinout) as min
    ->   FROM test.timeclock
    ->   GROUP BY user,DATE(timeinout)) as tcmin
    -> ON (tcmin.user=tc.user AND DATE(tcmin.min)=DATE(tc.timeinout))
    -> LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
    -> user,
    -> MAX(timeinout) as max
    ->   FROM test.timeclock
    ->   GROUP BY user,DATE(timeinout)) as tcmax
    -> ON (tcmax.user=tc.user AND DATE(tcmax.max)=DATE(tc.timeinout))
    -> WHERE 
    -> tc.timeinout>='2015-07-27'
    -> AND tc.timeinout<'2015-08-03'
    -> AND tc.user=1
    -> GROUP BY tc.user,DATE(tc.timeinout)
    -> ORDER BY tc.timeinout ASC;
+------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+---------+
| user | min                 | max                 | WeekDay   | Minutes |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+---------+
|    1 | 2015-07-27 20:20:32 | 2015-07-27 20:29:25 | Monday    |       8 |
|    1 | 2015-07-28 20:32:04 | 2015-07-28 20:36:28 | Tuesday   |       4 |
|    1 | 2015-07-29 20:40:00 | 2015-07-29 20:45:39 | Wednesday |       5 |
|    1 | 2015-07-30 20:20:32 | 2015-07-30 20:20:56 | Thursday  |       0 |
|    1 | 2015-07-31 20:29:25 | 2015-07-31 20:32:04 | Friday    |       2 |
|    1 | 2015-08-01 20:36:28 | 2015-08-01 20:40:00 | Saturday  |       3 |
|    1 | 2015-08-02 20:20:32 | 2015-08-02 20:40:00 | Sunday    |      19 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+---------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

### EDIT 2:

```
SELECT 
    user,
    '2020-01-01' as date,
    'Total for current results:' as WeekDay,
    SUM(Minutes) as Minutes
FROM (SELECT 
            tc.user,
            DATE(tc.timeinout) as date,
            CASE 
                WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=0 THEN 'Monday' 
                WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=1 THEN 'Tuesday'
                WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=2 THEN 'Wednesday'
                WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=3 THEN 'Thursday'
                WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=4 THEN 'Friday'
                WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=5 THEN 'Saturday'
                WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=6 THEN 'Sunday' END AS WeekDay,
            TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,tcmin.min,tcmax.max) AS Minutes
        FROM test.timeclock AS tc
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                    user,
                    MIN(timeinout) as min
                  FROM test.timeclock
                  GROUP BY user,DATE(timeinout)) as tcmin
            ON (tcmin.user=tc.user AND DATE(tcmin.min)=DATE(tc.timeinout))
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                    user,
                    MAX(timeinout) as max
                  FROM test.timeclock
                  GROUP BY user,DATE(timeinout)) as tcmax
            ON (tcmax.user=tc.user AND DATE(tcmax.max)=DATE(tc.timeinout))
        WHERE 
            tc.timeinout>='2015-07-27'
            AND tc.timeinout<'2015-08-03'
            AND tc.user=1
        GROUP BY tc.user,DATE(tc.timeinout)
        ORDER BY date ASC) AS Total
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    tc.user,
    DATE(tc.timeinout) as date,
    CASE 
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=0 THEN 'Monday' 
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=1 THEN 'Tuesday'
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=2 THEN 'Wednesday'
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=3 THEN 'Thursday'
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=4 THEN 'Friday'
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=5 THEN 'Saturday'
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=6 THEN 'Sunday' END AS WeekDay,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,tcmin.min,tcmax.max) AS Minutes
FROM test.timeclock AS tc
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
            user,
            MIN(timeinout) as min
          FROM test.timeclock
          GROUP BY user,DATE(timeinout)) as tcmin
    ON (tcmin.user=tc.user AND DATE(tcmin.min)=DATE(tc.timeinout))
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
            user,
            MAX(timeinout) as max
          FROM test.timeclock
          GROUP BY user,DATE(timeinout)) as tcmax
    ON (tcmax.user=tc.user AND DATE(tcmax.max)=DATE(tc.timeinout))
WHERE 
    tc.timeinout>='2015-07-27'
    AND tc.timeinout<'2015-08-03'
    AND tc.user=1
GROUP BY tc.user,DATE(tc.timeinout)
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

Comment: One more question if you don't mind :) Can you tell me how to get the total for all hours within the results? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit your question with your expected output or make a new one :)

Comment: Output expected has been updated. :)

Comment: But, Aren't you using Php? Make a sum of the field `Minutes`?

Comment: Yea, I am being dumb haha. Once again thanks for all your help.

Comment: @NUGGET don't worry, *Everyday we learn something new*.